# Flash : Trace not working

Tags: flash, debugging

Apparently trace stoped working in a perticular file its working fine on everything else. but my main file. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Make sure you've installed *debug* version of flash player.

Comment: debug flash player dont puts out the trace statements, thats why this tool was developed http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/ or did i miss something?

Comment: Flash tracer was not working tried it. The problem was with the publish settings of the swf as told by antpaw. I checked ommit trace actoins accidently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable trace for each published swf, go to the file -> public settings -> flash tab
make sure "omit trace actions" is unchecked

Comment: Thanks for the help it was the same reason :)